# BeLux User Group - September 28, 2017

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

**Date/Time (CEST)**: Thursday, September 28, 2017, 18:00

**Date/Time (UTC)**: Thursday, September 28, 2017, 16:00

**Location**: Zebrastraat 32, 9000 Gent, Belgium

**RSVP**: https://www.meetup.com/Sitecore-User-Group-Belgium/events/241110601/

**Agenda**

- *Session 1: Sitecore on Microsoft Azure PaaS*

In this session, you will learn how to make the most of Sitecore on an Azure PaaS environment.  Topics will Include deployment, customisation, Continuous Integration and monitoring / general insights.

Speaker: *Katrien De Graeve - Microsoft*

- *Session 2: An Azure ARM deployment story*

In this session, Rob will share his learnings on how to setup an Azure PaaS environment in detail, including preparing the files, ARM and PowerShell scripts, as well as configuring Visual Studio Team Services to leverage the power of scripted provisioning for true Blue Green Deployments. Of course there will be time provided for questions and discussions concerning this fascinating topic.

Speaker: *Rob Habraken - Sitecore MVP*

- *Session 3: Sitecore presents Commerce*

Sitecore will provide a deeper insight and understanding into their Commerce solution and roadmap through a general presentation and demo.

Speaker: *Johan Becue - Sitecore Solution Architect*

- Network and mingle time

Twitter: #SugBeLux

Comment: Done. Community Bulletin promotion has begun.